# Redirect to another route when `mapHooks` fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have defined following `mapHooks`:

```
const mapHooks = {
  fetch: ({ dispatch, params }) => dispatch(fetchPost(params.postId)).catch(() => {
    console.log('catch');
  }),
};
```

Sometimes, post cannot be found and I'd like to redirect user to the another page.
When I `catch` the error I tried to call `push('/foo')` to redirect to `/foo` page, but it does nothing (`push` comes from `react-router-redux`.

How can I redirect user properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` function that comes with `react-router-redux` is an **action creator**, meaning that it returns an action that you need to `dispatch`.  So you need to call it like this: `dispatch(push('/foo'))`

Also, check if you have your **`routerMiddleware`** installed correctly.

Comment: That's it - calling the `dispatch` on the `push` works like a charm!